# The roots of $x^2-2x+3=0$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Find the equation whose roots are: $\alpha+2$, $\beta+2$. Not sure of answer in book.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The roots of $x^2-2x+3=0$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Find the equation whose roots are: $\alpha+2$, $\beta+2$. Not sure of answer in book.

My working:

$\alpha+\beta=2, \alpha\beta=3$

$(\alpha+2)+(\beta+2)=\alpha+\beta+4=6$

$(\alpha+2)(\beta+2)=\alpha\beta+2(\alpha+\beta)=7$

Therefore, equation whose roots are $\alpha+2, \beta+2$ is $x^2-6x+7=0$

Answer in book is $x^2-6x+11=0$

Comment: The answer in the book is what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$(\alpha+2)(\beta +2)=\alpha\beta+2(\alpha+\beta)\color{red}{+4}$$

Comment: Woops. Now I feel silly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

Let $y=x+2$ so that $x=y-2$ and $(y-2)^2-2(y-2)+3=0$ or $y^2-6y+11=0$

Such an approach may be possible when all the roots of the first equation are transformed in the same way to get the second, and sometimes has advantages of simplicity and of doing all the coefficients at once.

Comment: Will make note of the alternate approach under the conditions you specified. Thank you.