# If $a$, $b$ are the roots of $x^2-2x+3$.Then the equation whose roots are $a^3-3a^2+5a-2$ and $b^3-b^2+b+5$ is:

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $a$, $b$ are the roots of $x^2-2x+3$.Then the equation whose roots are $a^3-3a^2+5a-2$ and $b^3-b^2+b+5$ is:

I have not been able to find a better method than to calculate $a$ and $b$ then substitute them into the roots for the new polynomial.

I believe this question can't be transformed in a similar manner as mentioned in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531826/the-roots-of-x2-2x3-0-are-alpha-and-beta-find-the-equation-whose-root) as the new roots are asymmetrical.

Does a better method than the lackluster substitution, exist?

The answer is:

> $x^2-3x+2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x^2=2x-3$, we get that $x^3=2x^2-3x=x-6$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
a^3-3a^2+5a-2
&=(a-6)-3(2a-3)+5a-2\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
b^3-b^2+b+5
&=(b-6)-(2b-3)+b+5\\
&=2
\end{align}
$$
It is easy to find an equation which has roots of $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Never thought about using the initial polynomial to create a reduction formula absolutely radical!

Comment: @CaptainQuestion In this case it's actually easier to use long division to compute the remainder - I added that to my answer to show how easy it is.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

As $a,b$ are the roots of $x^2-2x+3=0$

$a^3-3a^2+5a-3=(a^2-2a+3)(a-1)+1=1$

Similarly for $b$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ x^3-3x^2+5x-2\,\bmod\, \color{#c00}{x^2-2x+3}\, =\, \color{#0a0}1\ $ (and $= \color{#90f}2$ for the other). So we seek a polynomial with roots $\color{#0a0}1$ and $\color{#90f}2,\,$ e.g. $\ (x-\color{#0a0}1)(x-\color{#90f}2)$

**Remark** $ $ The remainder is quickly computable by long division (ignoring the unneeded quotient)

$$\begin{align}
&\ \ \ 1\ {-}3\ \ \ \, 5\,\ {-}2\\
&\color{#c00}{{-}1\,\ \ \  2\ {-}3}\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ {-}1\ \ \ \ 2\ \ {-}2\\
&\color{#c00}{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \    1\ {-}2\ \ \ \ \ 3}\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad\ \  \color{#0a0}1
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\quad$$